# Does the setting time_out in mysql affect JDBC connection pool?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling

It's usually set to 60 seconds.

But I think con pool will hold the connection, so is there any conflict? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Glassfish Wiki:

idle-timeout-in-seconds
        maximum time in seconds, that a connection can remain idle in
        the pool. After this time, the pool implementation can close
        this connection. ====>Note that this does not control connection
        timeouts enforced at the database server side<====. Adminsitrators
        are advised to keep this timeout shorter than the EIS
        connection timeout (if such timeouts are configured on the
        specific EIS), to prevent accumulation of unusable connection
        in Application Server.